InterBase find these character (Code 13: Carriage Return (CR) Code 10: Line Feed (LF) ) in database
I am using InterBase 2007 to connect and update information in a database. I am importing data from a SQL Server database, while working on InterBase database.gdb file using Delphi in a DBgrid
I am getting a line break in some field as
"Cabezanellosa
, Salamanca"

While W want it to be like
"Cabezanellosa, Salamanca"

After copying the break character and search that on https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect, I got the character is UTF-8(10) and UTF-8(13) in decimal. I want to replace them with an empty string.
I use a program made by my office to export the data to a text file. When any field has this line break, that software stops operation and shows an error.
While working in SQL Server, I can easily find and replace those character using this query
SELECT * FROM data WHERE BIRTH_PLACE LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + '%' OR BIRTH_PLACE LIKE '%' + CHAR(13) + '%'

UPDATE data 
SET BIRTH_PLACE = REPLACE(REPLACE(BIRTH_PLACE, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')
WHERE BIRTH_PLACE LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + '%' OR BIRTH_PLACE LIKE '%' + CHAR(13) + '%'

This query does not work in InterBase 2007. I also tried different AI generated query from multiple AI website as chatGPT, Claude, Copilot
but none of them are working.
Is there any way I can update these character to empty string using InterBase 2007?

Disclaimer: I don't use InterBase, but its sibling/fork Firebird, but in this regard I think they are close enough that I can provide an answer.
The problem is that CHAR(10) in InterBase is only valid syntax for defining a fixed length datatype of 10 characters; CHAR is not a function to define a character value in InterBase. In addition, concatenation in InterBase is done with ||, not +.
To be able to define a character value, you need to use the UDF ascii_char. UDFs (User Defined Functions) are not built-in in the SQL language of InterBase, and must be explicitly defined in the current database. If your database doesn't have it defined yet, you will need to explicitly define it with:
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION ascii_char
INTEGER
RETURNS CSTRING(1) FREE_IT
ENTRY_POINT 'IB_UDF_ascii_char' MODULE_NAME 'ib_udf';

Then you can use it in your query, for example:
SELECT * 
FROM data 
WHERE BIRTH_PLACE LIKE '%' || ascii_char(10) || '%' 
OR BIRTH_PLACE LIKE '%' || ascii_char(13) || '%'

Unfortunately, InterBase doesn't have a REPLACE function, nor a "standard" UDF for it. So you'll need to look for one. The FreeAdhocUDF library provides one (see F_REPLACESTRING in String functions), but given it was last updated in 2010, I'm not sure if it still works on recent versions of InterBase.
Alternatively, you could do the cleanup in the source database before your export it to InterBase, or do the cleanup in the application you use to produce the text file, or clean up the text file with - for example - Notepad++.
And finally, consider migrating from InterBase to Firebird, as it has a far richer collection of built-in functions compared to the number of built-in and UDFs InterBase has. (This is a bit tongue-in-cheek, because changing your database system is not something you should do on a whim.)

After your comment
i downloaded the firebird to check how FireBird work
In FireBird you can run this query
FireBird supports this but InterBase don't, at least not the InterBase 2007
As per your external function it's already there but the query does not work.
As it's not supported i asked  to superior to get it removed before getting the data from SQL server to InterBase.

@Habiburnik It's Firebird, not FireBird :)
